# Remove rows if value in col1 is in col2 and value in col2 is in col1

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am working in base R (no tidy verse please). I have the following dataframe in R:

```
> geneA  
[1] "GNG7"  "GNG7"  "GNG7"  "GNG12" "GNG12" "GNG12" "GNG2"  "GNG2"  "GNG2"  
[10] "GNG5"  "GNG5"  "GNG5" 

> geneB  
 [1] "GNG12" "GNG5"  "GNG2"  "GNG7"  "GNG5"  "GNG2"  "GNG5"  "GNG12" "GNG7"  
[10] "GNG12" "GNG7"  "GNG2"
```

(some data wrangling to create extra column GENE_PAIR)

```
> GNGdata
    geneA geneB  GENE_PAIR  
1  GNG7 GNG12 GNG7;GNG12  
2  GNG7  GNG5  GNG7;GNG5  
3  GNG7  GNG2  GNG7;GNG2  
4 GNG12  GNG7 GNG12;GNG7  
5 GNG12  GNG5 GNG12;GNG5  
6 GNG12  GNG2 GNG12;GNG2  
7  GNG2  GNG5  GNG2;GNG5  
8  GNG2 GNG12 GNG2;GNG12  
9  GNG2  GNG7  GNG2;GNG7  
10  GNG5 GNG12 GNG5;GNG12  
11  GNG5  GNG7  GNG5;GNG7  
12  GNG5  GNG2  GNG5;GNG2
```

As you can see, there are duplicated GENE_PAIRs (1 and 4, 2 and 11, etc). I want to keep only 1 pair. For instance, the pair GNG7;GNG12 exists, so I want to exclude the pair GNG12,GNG7 from my new dataframe.

I am expecting this result:

```
> GNGdata_filtered  
    geneA geneB  GENE_PAIR  
1  GNG7 GNG12 GNG7;GNG12  
2  GNG7  GNG5  GNG7;GNG5  
3  GNG7  GNG2  GNG7;GNG2  
4 GNG12  GNG5 GNG12;GNG5  
5 GNG12  GNG2 GNG12;GNG2  
66  GNG2  GNG5  GNG2;GNG5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @benson23's answer, but using `sort()` in the `paste()` function:

```r
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~geneA, ~geneB,
"GNG7", "GNG12", 
"GNG7",  "GNG5", 
"GNG7",  "GNG2", 
"GNG12",  "GNG7",
"GNG12",  "GNG5",
"GNG12",  "GNG2",
"GNG2",  "GNG5", 
"GNG2", "GNG12", 
"GNG2",  "GNG7", 
"GNG5", "GNG12", 
"GNG5",  "GNG7", 
"GNG5",  "GNG2")

dat$gene_pair <- apply(dat[,c("geneA", "geneB")], 1, function(x)paste(sort(x), collapse=";"))
dat <- dat[!duplicated(dat$gene_pair), ]
dat
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   geneA geneB gene_pair 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     
#> 1 GNG7  GNG12 GNG12;GNG7
#> 2 GNG7  GNG5  GNG5;GNG7 
#> 3 GNG7  GNG2  GNG2;GNG7 
#> 4 GNG12 GNG5  GNG12;GNG5
#> 5 GNG12 GNG2  GNG12;GNG2
#> 6 GNG2  GNG5  GNG2;GNG5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I found this useful and works on other df. However I didn't quite follow how it is processing the data to delete duplicates. I am assuming sort(x) orders alphabetically and then the function pairs the values in a way that outputs a 'pair of genes' in an alphabetical manner thus creating (if any) duplicate row values across the df ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `pmax` and `pmin` to generate sorted pair of genes. Then remove the duplicated ones.

```r
GNGdata$geneAB <- with(GNGdata, paste0(pmax(geneA, geneB), ";", pmin(geneA, geneB)))
GNGdata_filtered <- GNGdata[!duplicated(GNGdata$geneAB),-4]

  geneA geneB  GENE_PAIR
1  GNG7 GNG12 GNG7;GNG12
2  GNG7  GNG5  GNG7;GNG5
3  GNG7  GNG2  GNG7;GNG2
5 GNG12  GNG5 GNG12;GNG5
6 GNG12  GNG2 GNG12;GNG2
7  GNG2  GNG5  GNG2;GNG5
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create an index (`idx`) of duplicated genes after using `mixedsort`, then index the data frame on those that are not duplicated:

```
idx <- duplicated(unlist(lapply(lapply(strsplit(df$GENE_PAIR,";"), gtools::mixedsort),
       function(x) paste(x, collapse = ";"))))

df[!idx,]

#  geneA geneB  GENE_PAIR
# 1  GNG7 GNG12 GNG7;GNG12
# 2  GNG7  GNG5  GNG7;GNG5
# 3  GNG7  GNG2  GNG7;GNG2
# 5 GNG12  GNG5 GNG12;GNG5
# 6 GNG12  GNG2 GNG12;GNG2
# 7  GNG2  GNG5  GNG2;GNG5
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R, we can try `order` + `unique` like below

```
transform(
    setNames(
        as.data.frame(
            unique(t(matrix(
                c(t(df))[order(c(t(row(df))), c(t(df)))],
                ncol(df)
            )))
        ),
        names(df)
    ),
    GENE_PAIR = paste0(geneA, ";", geneB)
)
```

which gives

```
  geneA geneB  GENE_PAIR
1 GNG12  GNG7 GNG12;GNG7
2  GNG5  GNG7  GNG5;GNG7
3  GNG2  GNG7  GNG2;GNG7
4 GNG12  GNG5 GNG12;GNG5
5 GNG12  GNG2 GNG12;GNG2
6  GNG2  GNG5  GNG2;GNG5
```

---

If you don't mind using other packages besides base R, we can try `igraph` package like below

```
library(igraph)
df %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
    simplify() %>%
    get.data.frame() %>%
    set_names(names(df)) %>%
    mutate(GENE_PAIR = do.call(paste, c(., sep = ";")))
```

which gives

```
  geneA geneB  GENE_PAIR
1  GNG7 GNG12 GNG7;GNG12
2  GNG7  GNG2  GNG7;GNG2
3  GNG7  GNG5  GNG7;GNG5
4 GNG12  GNG2 GNG12;GNG2
5 GNG12  GNG5 GNG12;GNG5
6  GNG2  GNG5  GNG2;GNG5
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(geneA = c("GNG7", "GNG7", "GNG7", "GNG12", "GNG12",
"GNG12", "GNG2", "GNG2", "GNG2", "GNG5", "GNG5", "GNG5"), geneB = c("GNG12",
"GNG5", "GNG2", "GNG7", "GNG5", "GNG2", "GNG5", "GNG12", "GNG7",
"GNG12", "GNG7", "GNG2")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4",
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @GregorThomas aha, didn't see that. I am deleting my solution

Comment: @GregorThomas now I added one base R solution

Comment: You could also make your `igraph` solution not depend on `tidyverse` packages pretty easily. (Was trying to mention that when you deleted your post.) OP is *probably* looking for a no-dependency solution, but that would at least make it a single-dependency solution. And we're far enough out from launch that `|>` is generally accepted

Answer (score 0):

If `d` = your data frame:

Here I create a matrix with integers only and sort them from low to high. Then we can create an index of non-duplicated values.

```
tmp <- apply(d[,1:2],2,sub,pattern = "\\D+",replacement = "")
tmp2 <- matrix(as.integer(tmp),12,2)
i <- !duplicated(t(apply(tmp2,1,sort)))
d[i,]
```